# Change an Image in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to change an image in JavaScript. I've looked everywhere and it states to use
`document.getElementbyId("image").src = "image2.jpg"` but it isn't working. I made sure the script is at the bottom after the image tag in the html.

html code:

```
<img id="image" src="image1.jpg">
```

JavaScript code:

```
document.getElementbyId("image").src = "image2.jpg"
```

Am I missing anything?

Comment: Don't know. Provide us a sample of your code, or all your code, so that we can diagnose your issue better. We can't see how you've implemented it etc, so we can't assist. Alternatively; you can find an example here: https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_intro_lightbulb or this example: https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_lightbulb

Comment: looks fair enough ... except it's `document.getElementById` - what errors do you see in the browser **developer** tools console?

Comment: Just want to point out that Jaromanda is stating that the B and I should be capitals, not lowercase. (took me a while to work out that comment myself)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have misspelled `document.getElementbyId`. The correct one is `document.getElementById`

Answer (score 0):

You need 2 pieces for your JS code: first select, and then manipulate:

select: (& note that the 'By' in getElementById is capitalized)

```
const img1 = document.getElementById("image");
```

manipulate:

```
img1.setAttribute("src", "image2.jpg");
```

I referenced this [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute).